# Merge a small site into a larger one while preserving SEO

Tags: seo, redirects, traffic, site-move

I have a site with 10 pages of small tools for developers. I have a good traffic on it.

I want to move all site data to be part of another big portal (hub for developer tools). I also want to redirect the old domain to the new one. 
My main goal is to preserve traffic and redirect it to a new resource.

Is it possible? Will I lose all traffic? I have spend about one year to increase traffic on initial site, so it is important to save at least 80% of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of an amendment to WSUs answer. Google pass 100% link juice with 301 redirects, and have for over 3 years. This was confirmed by Gary Illyes [tweet](https://twitter.com/methode/status/757923179641839616)

However, if you're worried about ranking for other search engines, then it might be worth contacting people. Otherwise don't bother, as it's not worth the time.

Comment: While redirects preserve link juice, it is still common to see ranking drops when moving between sites.  The Google site move tool lets Google know you are changing your domain name and prevents ranking drops in most cases for that. Unfortunately the tool can't be used for site merges.

Comment: The potential ranking drop has still nothing to do with the redirects, and more to do with the 200 or so ranking factors used for PageRank, among them domain name and domain age (albeit a very small factor). The only drawback with redirects is if Google retains your old pages in its' index for believing it just being a mistake or a hacked domain. That's why it's generally safer to use the site merge tool or canonicals first. When using canonicals, follow through with redirects after pages have been crawled.

Answer (score 4):

The standard practice is what you already suggest, moving the pages and setting up redirections (make sure to redirect each page to its new equivalent).

However, 301 redirects do not preserve all of the SEO value or link juice. Therefore, there is no guarantee that you will be able to achieve the same ranking/traffic with the new pages.

I think your best bet is to look at the backlinks pointing to the original pages, contact the people who link to them and ask them to link to the new address instead.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If another portal has 0 traffic then you would lose your traffic for short time because 301 redirection takes time to work without any concrete guarantee of recovery but there are many precautions, you need to take when you are merging existing contents.